# white-space: pre-wrap doesn't work while passing text as a prop in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am just passing a long-text as a prop into a child component in Vue project.

child component:

```
    <template>
      <div class="story">
        <p class="story__content">{{ content }}</p>
      </div>
    </template>
```

parent component:

```
             <story
                content="Before your trip, I recommend researching the destination to find the most interesting photo opportunities.\n I always research the location I’m traveling to.\n I do this extensively and obsessively!"
            />
```

I tried css like this in

tag of the child component.

```
.story__content {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

But it shows no line break but shows text as is like this:
[image]

Does anybody have a similar experience to this?
Than you in advance!

Comment: I got same issue today while working with vue3, Unfortunately i did not find any solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Update your code adding v-html directive to your p tag, that way the `content` prop is used as html code:

```
<template>
  <div class="story">
    <p class="story__content" v-html="content" />
  </div>
</template>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)